# MYSQL/PHP Pagination shows 9 pages regardless of results returned

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm using the following code for an events page mysql query to show paginated results from the current date however it will display 9 pages in the pagination links even when the results would only total 3 pages etc.  Can someone help me identify why this is happening?

```
            $per_page = 25;
            $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('CompName') FROM my_db");
            $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);
            $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
            $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(StartDate, '%d/%m/%Y') StartDate, CompName, HostState, Location,  competitiontypedesc FROM my_db WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE() LIMIT $start, $per_page"); 

            while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo"
            <li class='kleo-masonry-item event-item'> 
            <div class='member-inner-list animated animate-when-almost-visible bottom-to-top start-animation grey-border'> 
            <div class='event-cell event-date-cell'>
            <p class='no-margin'>" . $query_row["StartDate"] . "</p>
            </div>
            <div class='event-cell name'>
            <p class='no-margin'>" . $query_row["CompName"] ." " .$query_row["LastName"]. "</p></div>
            <div class='event-cell'>
            <p class='no-margin'>" . $query_row["Location"] . "</p>
            </div>
            <div class='event-cell'>
            <p class='no-margin'>" . $query_row["HostState"] . "</p>
            </div>
            </li>"
            ;   
            }

            $prev = $page - 1;
            $next = $page + 1;

            if(!($page <= 1)){
            echo "<a href='?page=$prev'><</a> ";}

            if($pages >= 1){
            for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){
            echo ($x == $page) ? '<b><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></b> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';}
            }

            if(!($page >= $pages)){
            echo "<a href='?page=$next'>></a> ";}
            }
            }
```

Comment: Please, read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php .

Comment: What does `echo $pages;` show you?

Comment: Thanks Michas, realise its depreciated and will update, code is from an older tutorial

Comment: echo $pages; shows '9'

Comment: @ParkProductions An answer has been given below, explaining the thing you're doing wrong. Hopefully *that* answer will resolve your issue.

Comment: Anyone willing to help with a mysqli port of that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you count number of row, you always count in whole the table.

```
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`CompName`) FROM my_db");
```

But when you get data, you have a condition on StartDate in where clause.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(StartDate, '%d/%m/%Y') StartDate, CompName, HostState, Location,  competitiontypedesc FROM my_db WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE() LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

So, you should add the same condtion of StartDate in count query.

```
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`CompName`) FROM my_db WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE()");
```

Actually, count(*) will be better than count(`CompName`).

```
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE()");
```

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: If you use MyISAM tables, count(*) will have a better performance.

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE()");

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

If you use Innodb, count(*) and count(`ComName`) have the same performance.

Comment: Thanks Tung that worked, its now displaying the correct amount of pages.